# Which eclipse perspective custom icon file format do I need

Tags: eclipse, icons

I have created a custom eclipse perspective and want to set a custom icon for that perspective. I read that the icon should be in 16x16 format. I tried to provide .ico, .png, .gif files to the extension point but no format seems to work. What do I wrong ?

`<extension
         id="de.mdsd.xtext.sponsorrun.application.joggathon.editor.perspectives"
         name="Joggathon Editor Perspectives"
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="de.mdsd.xtext.sponsorrun.application.PerspectiveFactory1"
            icon="icons/Joggathon-Group16.png"
            id="de.mdsd.xtext.sponsorrun.application.joggathon.editor"
            name="Joggathon">
      </perspective>
   </extension>`

Comment: When you make these changes, are you remembering to **Clear the Configuration Area** in the options of your **Runtime Workbench** launcher?

Answer (score 1):

.jpg, .gif or .png are all OK. For your example make sure the png file is in the 'icons' directory of the plugin.

You need to specify the `-clean` option when you run your test to make sure changes to the perspective are seen.

Also make sure the 'icons' directory appears in the 'build.properties' file.